# says that Namespace 'already been declared' when I've only declared it once

Tags: javascript, html, require, google-closure

Newbie question here as I am just beginning game development with `lime.js`, but I'm receiving this error below, and I for the life of me cannot figure out why this error says that `'moba.Bullet'` is already declared since I've only provided it once!

This is the full error:

```
Uncaught Error: Namespace "moba.Bullet" already declared. 
   goog.provide base.js:
   (anonymous function)
```

When looking at the error's location in base.js, I am given this code:

```
goog.provide = function(name) {
  if (!COMPILED) {
    // Ensure that the same namespace isn't provided twice.
    // A goog.module/goog.provide maps a goog.require to a specific file
    if (goog.isProvided_(name)) {
      throw Error('Namespace "' + name + '" already declared.');
    }
  }
```

I have only provided the namespace **once**! This makes this even more confusing!!

To understand this problem, it will help to see my file structure.

the **folder structure** of my lime.js game looks like so:

```
limejs >
  moba >
    moba.html
    moba.js
    bullet.js
  bin >
    lime.py
    projects
    external >
  closure
  box2D
```

and i even ran bin/lime.py update so moba.js (the main js file) would recognize bullet.js!

And now we get to how I call each file with goog.provide and goog.require.

```
moba.js >
  goog.provide('moba');
  goog.require('moba.Bullet');

bullet.js >
  goog.provide('moba.Bullet');
Pretty standard, right?!
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried recreating the project through the command line but with no love. So please help and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the first line you see the opening tag, then the second line for if (!COMPILED) has an opening tag, then on the fifth line is if (goog.isProvided_(name)) and another opening tag, but only two closing tags at the end of that code, I would think there should be a third one.

Comment: Hi Amber, I think the unbalanced curly braces you noticed are not a part of the poster's problem but rather a byproduct of a careless copy and paste by the poster. You might ask via comments to the original post for them to clarify and add more context to help with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie also but looking at the following code I noticed a missing closing tag for the first if statement:

```
goog.provide = function(name) {
  if (!COMPILED) {
    // Ensure that the same namespace isn't provided twice.
    // A goog.module/goog.provide maps a goog.require to a specific file
    if (goog.isProvided_(name)) {
      throw Error('Namespace "' + name + '" already declared.');
    }
  }
```

sometimes forgetting to close an if statement can cause a lot of issues.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is the missing closing tag? I did not see it! I am having the same problem.

Comment: my problem was due to a duplicate <script> tag